# chmod all .htaccess files under all website dirs under public_html dir

Tags: security, bash, linux, wordpress

This is my code to chmod all .htaccess files under all website dirs under `public_html` dir.

The reason I use this code is to make sure WordPress plugins won't "freak out" and change my `.htaccess` file undesirably.

This is a shared server environment so I can't access `htppd.conf` instead, and must edit the different `.htaccess` files per each site, with the below code:

```
for dir in "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il}/; do
  if pushd "$dir"; then
    chmod 644 .htaccess
    popd
  fi
done 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of manually scanning each files and directory and testing if they are a directory using `pushd`, I would directly try to target `.htaccess` files using [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```sh
find "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il} -name ".htaccess"
```

Then, to apply the proper permissions, you can use the `-exec` option of `find`:

```sh
find "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il} -name ".htaccess" -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why redirect the loop's `stderr` to `/dev/null`.
What do you expect to go wrong there?
If the `chmod` fails, I think it would be better to know about it than to quietly ignore.
Same for `pushd`.
If there are no matching files, that will lead to `pushd` on the literal unmatched pattern, which will probably fail.
If you want to avoid the loop in case nothing matches the glob pattern, you could do `shopt -s nullglob` before the loop.

In any case, 
you don't need a loop to do this,
you can use a single `chmod` command:

```
chmod 644 "$HOME"/public_html/*.{com,co.il}/.htaccess
```

This will fail if there are no matches of the glob pattern, but well, isn't that good like that?
If it isn't, then you can do as you did in your script,
and redirect `stderr`.

Comment: +1. You are right, the stderr redirection is indeed redundant, if something goes wrong (no `.htacess` files under a given dir), which shouldn't happen, it is best to have an error.